# Converting list to dataframe for use in ggplot

Tags: r, list, ggplot2

I've got a list called `res` that looks like this:

```
[[1]]
     [,1]     [,2]    
[1,] 275.0637 273.9386
[2,] 5.707791 5.755798

[[2]]
     [,1]     [,2]    
[1,] 126.8435 59.08806
[2,] 4.867521 3.258545

[[3]]
     [,1]     [,2]    
[1,] 23.50188 60.96321
[2,] 2.036354 3.737291
```

The list contains results from a simulation run a total of 6 times.  I set a parameter of interest at three different values, '0' (ie., [[1]]), '25' (i.e.,[[2]]), and '50' (i.e.,[[3]]).  Since the model includes a great deal of randomness I ran the model twice for each value (i.e., [,1], [,2]).  I asked the model to record two results, 'time feeding' (i.e., [1,] and 'distance traveled' (i.e., [2,]) for each iteration.  Ultimately I will iterate the model 30 times for each variable setting.  I'd like to use `ggplot` to create a boxplot showing 'time feeding' and 'distance traveled' for each of the three simulation settings (i.e., 0,25,50).  I believe `ggplot` can't plot a list so I tried to convert `res` to a dataframe using `res2 <- data.frame(res)`  which looked like:

```
        X1       X2     X1.1     X2.1     X1.2     X2.2
1 275.0637 273.9386 126.8435 59.08806 23.50188 60.96321
2 5.707791 5.755798 4.867521 3.258545 2.036354 3.737291
```

This doesn't quite look right to me because now the results from all three simulations are on the same row.  Any help on bringing this data into `ggplot` to create a boxplot with would be really helpful.  Thanks in advance!

--Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming ll is your list , you can use `do.call` and `rbind` like this :

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(seq_along(ll),
        function(x)data.frame(ll[[x]],iter=x)))

           X..1.      X..2. iter
[1,]  275.063700 273.938600    1
[2,]    5.707791   5.755798    1
[1,]1 126.843500  59.088060    2
[2,]1   4.867521   3.258545    2
[1,]2  23.501880  60.963210    3
[2,]2   2.036354   3.737291    3
```

**EDIT** after op clarication:

```
interest <- c(0,25,50)
 do.call(rbind,lapply(seq_along(ll),
        function(x)data.frame(x= unlist(ll[[x]]),interst=interest[x])))

                                               interst=interest[x] .... [TRUNCATED] 

                 x interst
X..1.1  275.063700       0
X..1.2    5.707791       0
X..2.1  273.938600       0
X..2.2    5.755798       0
X..1.11 126.843500      25
X..1.21   4.867521      25
X..2.11  59.088060      25
X..2.21   3.258545      25
X..1.12  23.501880      50
X..1.22   2.036354      50
X..2.12  60.963210      50
X..2.22   3.737291      50
```

**EDIT** since OP don't provide data here ll :

```
res <- list(read.table(text='
     [,1]     [,2]    
[1,] 275.0637 273.9386
[2,] 5.707791 5.755798'),
read.table(text='
     [,1]     [,2]    
[1,] 126.8435 59.08806
[2,] 4.867521 3.258545'),
read.table(text='
     [,1]     [,2]    
[1,] 23.50188 60.96321
[2,] 2.036354 3.737291'))
```

Comment: That's great!  Although is it possible to have the values in the two columns (e.g., 275.06, 273.93) be listed in a single column?  That way I can ask `ggplot` to `ggplot(res, aes(x=iter, y=X1)) + geom_boxplot())`

Comment: Thanks again!  Can the 'x' column be split into two columns such that 'time feeding' (i.e., 275, 273, 126, etc) and 'distance traveled' (i.e., 5.7,5.75,4.86,etc.) are separate?  Otherwise, I'm not sure how ggplot can recognize which variable to plot.

Comment: @user2359494 Try to understand my answer ! I will not do the job for you. Take the transpose and you get what you want: `do.call(rbind,lapply(seq_along(ll),function(x)data.frame(x= t((ll[[x]])), interst=interest[x])))`

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
names(res) = c("0", "25", "50")
m = reshape2::melt(res, id = 1)
```

but maybe it doesn't work, I tried it in my head because you didn't provide data in usable form.

Comment: it's unlikely to be the same type of data

Comment: Why? for me it is a list of 3 data.frames..?

Comment: from the display, they're probably matrices, initially